# Displaying images in draft mode for books

Tags: graphics, draft

I am writing my thesis in draft mode.

```
\documentclass[dissertation,draft]{univthesis}
```

The univthesis is a dissertation template like a book. However, when I include figures, I only see the figure name and box enclosing it. When draft mode is removed, I get what I want. So, I was wondering if there is a way to display images even in draft mode. I have both .eps and .pdf files in the current directory.

Comment: Seems it is defined by `univthesis`. We have to know how is defined in  `univthesis` to solve this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following setup:

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\documentclass[dissertation,draft]{univthesis}
```

This loads [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) before the `draft` option is set. Alternatively (preferred), don't load `graphicx` but reset the package option using

```
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
```

`Gin` contains the family of keys associated with [`graphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics)/`graphicx`.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{graphicx}` is better. Or, even better, `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` in the preamble. Anyway, it's a duplicate.